# How to degrade similar tool strip button procedures to a single in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm using ToolStrip and it's buttons to change GUI structure with an example code how i change GUIs with tool strip buttons. Are there any methods to use them more easy way like when clicked event of ToolStripButton handled it can call a single procedure etc.? In current case it seems i'm coding in a bad way.

For example if user click the Home button it highlights the button as selected and hides other panel elements and make visible Home's panel.

```
 Private Sub tsbHome_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbHome.Click
        tsbHome.Checked = True
        tsbTools.Checked = False
        tsbReport.Checked = False
        tsbAnalyze.Checked = False
'... Tool Strip Button lists continues...
        pnlHome.Visible = True
        pnlTools.Visible = False
        pnlReport.Visible = False
        pnlAnalyze.Visible = False
' ... Panel lists continues...
    End Sub
```

if user click the Tools button it highlights the button as selected and hides other panel elements and make visible Tool's panel.

```
 Private Sub tsbTools_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbTools.Click
        tsbHome.Checked = False
        tsbTools.Checked = True
        tsbReport.Checked = False
        tsbAnalyze.Checked = False
'... Tool Strip Button lists continues...
        pnlHome.Visible = False
        pnlTools.Visible = True
        pnlReport.Visible = False
        pnlAnalyze.Visible = False
' ... Panel lists continues...
    End Sub
```

Comment: We'll talk about everything later , but first , what is `**True**` ??

Comment: @zackraiyan thanks for your feedback i updated. I tried to make it bold.

Comment: so,what is it that u are trying to do ?and what is the issue with ur code ?

Comment: I'm using toolbar buttons to change my tool's GUI area with hide/unhide with Visual Studio's "panel" element.

Comment: what is the issue then ?

Comment: @zackraiyan The panel will change with 20 different toolbar buttons that means as i used currently; i'm duplicate all features 20 times and change True/False options. Same code block for 20 times i mean seems not efficient.

Comment: what are `pnlAnalyze` , `tsbHome` and all others ? i assume they are toolsrip items ?

Comment: @zackraiyan "tsb" prefix of ToolStripButtons, "pnl" is prefix of the Panels. tsbHome.Checked -> Toolbar button "Home" seems as active button. pnlAnalyze -> Panel of the my Analyze gui. It contains gui elements of my Analyze section of Tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two tricks to making this code much simpler. The first is knowing you can have more than one item in the `Handles` clause of an event method declaration. (You can also *omit* that clause, and use `AddHandler` to set up event handlers for a lot of controls to one method.)  The other trick is knowing how to use the `sender` argument to determine which of the several controls connected to this method was used.

Put those together, and you get one method that will work to change to any of your views.

```
Private Sub NavigationMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbHome.Click, tsbTools.Click, tsbReport.Click, tsbAnalyzer.Click
    'First Suspend Layout, to avoid extra screen re-draws
     Me.SuspendLayout()

     'Set your checkboxes
     tsbHome.Checked = sender Is tsbHome
     tsbTools.Checked = sender Is tsbTools
     tsbReport.Checked = sender Is tsbReport
     tsbAnalyze.Checked = sender Is tsbAnalyze

     'Then De-select EVERYTHING
     pnlHome.Visible = sender Is tsbHome
     pnlTools.Visible = sender Is tsbTools
     pnlReport.Visible = sender Is tsbReport
     pnlAnalyze.Visible = sender Is tsbAnalyze
      ' ... lists continues...

    'Finally, resume layout so all changes draw to the screen at once
    Me.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
```

We can make this simpler if you add code to the Form Load or InitializeComponent() method to put the panels and toolstrip buttons into lists:

```
Private ViewButtons As List(Of ToolStripButton)
Private ViewPanels As List(Of Panel)

 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ViewButtons = New List(Of ToolStripButton) From {tsbHome, tsbTools, tsbReport, tsbAnalyze}
    ViewPanels = New List(Of Panel) From {pnlHome, pnlTools, pnlReport, pnlAnalyze}

    For Each b In ViewButtons
       AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf NavigationMenuItem_Click
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub NavigationMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
     Me.SuspendLayout()

     For i As Integer = 0 To ViewButtons.Length - 1
         Dim selected As Boolean = ViewButtons(i) Is sender
         ViewButtons(i).Checked = selected
         ViewPanels(i).Visible = selected
    Next

    Me.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
```

Comment: tsbHome.Checked = sender Is tsbHome

Comment: @HansPassant I think I misunderstood how he's using the pnlXXX controls at first. He's basically already doing much of what I suggested via Custom Controls, so I'm re-writing a large part of this.

Comment: And, for the record...  I think custom controls are still better for this than using Panels, as it lets each view have its own class. But the panels are a good start.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn i think you're right. But first i need to learn more about the using of Custom Control. In fact i don't have so much experience on it. In custom control do you mean am i creating each gui as different forms ?

Comment: @Hakan A custom control effectively gives you a Panel, just like you have now for each of your different views. The difference is, it lets you keep the controls and code for each view isolated to it's own class.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn after hours i tried something but didnt succeeded. But answer really helpful guys.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Hello why did you remove the previous code? Is it wrong approach ? `Private currentView As Control

Private Sub NavigationMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbHome.Click, tsbTools.Click
     Me.SuspendLayout()
     Me.Controls.Remove(currentView)

     If sender = tsbHome Then
          currentView = new tsbHomeControl()
     Else if sender = tsbTools Then
          currentView = new tsbToolsControl()
     Else
         '...
     End If

     Me.Controls.Add(currentView)
     Me.ResumeLayout()
End Sub`